# New posts defaulting to '0' primary key

Tags: posts

When trying to create a new blog post, Wordpress is showing a Database error:

```
 WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`,`post_date`,`post_date_gmt`,`post_content`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_title`,`post_excerpt`,`post_status`,`post_type`,`comment_status`,`ping_status`,`post_password`,`post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`,`post_modified`,`post_modified_gmt`,`post_parent`,`menu_order`,`post_mime_type`,`guid`) VALUES (5,'2014-10-13 11:19:21','0000-00-00 00:00:00','','','Auto Draft','','auto-draft','post','open','open','','','','','2014-10-13 11:19:21','0000-00-00 00:00:00',0,0,'','') made by get_default_post_to_edit, wp_insert_post PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\..\..\..\httpdocs\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 567
```

I am able to edit past posts but the issue appears when trying to create a new post.

Any suggestions on a work around or fix to stop new posts from defaulting to the `0` as the `Primary Key`?

Wordpress V4.0 
PHP 5.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only my best guess. I can't see a definitive answer with the information provided.

---

The primary key for `wp_posts` should be set to `ID`. The primary key is giving the error. Since `ID` is not defined in the query, it is likely that the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value has been set to 0, or is no longer incrementing.

I would look into your database and find the AUTO_INCREMENT value. I bet it's set to 0 for some reason.

**Take a backup of your database before making any changes to the database.**

If the AUTO_INCREMENT value is set to 0, you want to set it to a value that hasn't yet been reached. Go to wp_posts and find the highest value `ID` and set it to one more than that (or a few more than that, just to be safe).

For example, if the highest value ID in wp_posts is 1000:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;
```

If this is not the issue, ensure that the PRIMARY_KEY for the table is set to `ID`.

Comment: Wow - thank you for your help RadGH. Much appreciated!

Comment: Tried, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: @Riz It only fixes the auto increment number being too low for a table. If you are trying to import an SQL file or insert a row manually while specifying post ID, you can't do that if IDs are already taken. You'll run into problems if the post also has postmeta because the ID must be the same for those rows. So you can't just change it either. Might be worth posting a new question.

Comment: Interestingly for me the problem was that `AUTO_INCREMENT` wasn't set for the ID. Make sure sure `A_I` is set for ID.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an update for this.

I uses the build in WP Core schema to ensure all WP Core tables are there (even in the future when 6.0 or higher is released ). It removes corrupt rows and re-adds keys an primary keys. The script (and more explanation) can be seen over here: https://wpindexfixer.tools.managedwphosting.nl/

No need to guess the auto-increment value too.

It is a free script.